# How to make up-to-date check notice non-file arguments in a Gradle Task?

Tags: gradle, build, build-process

Suppose I have a task class `MyTask` which reads an input file, does some conversion on it and writes an output file (`build.gradle`):

```groovy
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile File input
    @OutputFile File output
    String conversion

    @TaskAction void generate() {
        def content = input.text
        switch (conversion) {
            case "lower":
                content = content.toLowerCase()
                break;
            case "upper":
                content = content.toUpperCase()
                break;
        }
        output.write content
    }
}

project.task(type: MyTask, "myTask") {
    description = "Convert input to output based on conversion"
    input = file('input.txt')
    output = file('output.txt')
    conversion = "upper"
}
```

Now this all works fine, when I change `input.txt` or remove `output.txt` in the file system it executes again.
The problem is that **it doesn't execute if I change `"upper"` to `"lower"`**, which is wrong.

I can't (don't want to) put `build.gradle` in the inputs list because that would be a hack, also wouldn't work if, say, a command line argument changes what gets into the `myTask.conversion` field. Another one I thought of is to write the value into a file in a `setConversion()` method and put that on the `inputs` list, but again, that's a hack.

**How can I make gradle notice the change the *official* way?** Also if you know where can I read more about this, don't hold back on links ;)

I read [More about Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) and [Writing Custom Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html), but it gave me no clue.

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Does it work?

Comment: @Opal, yep, that works, thanks for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's helpful but I'd try:

```groovy
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFile File input
    @OutputFile File output
    String conversion

    @TaskAction void generate() {
        def content = input.text
        switch (conversion) {
            case "lower":
                content = content.toLowerCase()
                break;
            case "upper":
                content = content.toUpperCase()
                break;
        }
        output.write content
    }

    void setConversion(String conversion) {
       this.inputs.property('conversion', conversion)
       this.conversion = conversion
    }
}
```

Could you please check it?

Comment: I would put it in the constructor to prevent weird bugs when the setter is **not** called: `MyTask() { this.inputs.property('conversion', { conversion }) }`. Notice the `{}` around `conversion`, that's to make it read the value later, based on [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskInputs.html#property%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Answer (score 1):

There is a handy [`@Input` annotation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/Input.html), which is the same as [Opal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31053769/253468) (check its [source code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/core/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/project/taskfactory/InputPropertyAnnotationHandler.java#L32)), but little more concise:

```groovy
@Optional @Input String conversion
```

Here's a [Gradle goodness article](http://mrhaki.blogspot.hu/2010/10/gradle-goodness-add-incremental-build_14.html) about this.